# How to update docker-compose version on windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, boot2docker

I have docker and docker toolbox installed on Win10 machine.

`docker -v
Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825`

`docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe`

My docker version is up-to-date but the composer is not.

Any idea how can I update the composer version.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Docker compose releases](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) the latest version is 1.22.0 which is the one you have installed.

You have installed the latest docker compose, it was released 8 days ago.

**Update:**

In order to change your Docker compose file version just replace the line `version`,  by today 26th July 2018 to set the [latest docker compose file version](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-37) just replace it by:

```
version: '3.7'
```

Comment: Thank you, as @mulg0r has mentioned below, I want to know , how can i change my _docker-compose_ file version.

Answer (score 5):

You need upgrade your [Docker Desktop](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows) version.

Check, download and install lasted release version (Ex: Stable Releases of 2019):

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/

Each Docker Desktop release version has a specific version of Docker and docker-compose.

Answer (score 4):

Today, 26th July 2018, docker-compose latest version is 1.22. 
I don't know why do you say that your *docker-compose version* is not up to date.
Maybe you had a confusion with *docker-compose file version*

https://github.com/docker/compose/releases

Comment: thank you, you are right, I got confused between compose version and docker-compose file version. I am facing an issue and according to `https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5103` updating the version will fixed my error.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply go to the settings of docker desktop for Windows and select the option "Use Docker Compose V2"
[Docker Desktop for windows settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4H98.png)

Comment: I overlooked that in the Docker settings... smh. Docker should have included this step in their CLI command `docker-compose -v`

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue even though my docker-compose --version showed that the version of compose I had was 1.25.4. This didn't work, I had tried reinstalling compose and docker desktop entirely on windows 10.

Eventually I changed my installation to use Linux containers, and used experimental mode. Worked.

Good luck.